# How to read from a file in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to read in from a file named"parking.txt", and I want to read certain values from this file and output them to the screen. How can this be done? Can this be done?

The values in parking.txt is:

```
total 5
One 400
Five 300
Ten 200
Twenty 50
Quarter 500
```

In my code I would like to replace "line" with the appropriate value from the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile ("parking_account.txt");
    string line;

    getline(inputFile, line);

    cout <<"\n\t-------------------------------------------------------";
    cout <<"\n\t=======================================================";
    cout <<"\n\t              Parking Machine Accounts                 ";
    cout <<"\n\t=======================================================";
    cout <<"\n\tSr. No.  : Bill Name       :  Bill Count  :  Cost(in$) ";
    cout <<"\n\t-------------------------------------------------------";
    cout <<"\n\t       1 : One Dollar      :  " << line << "  :  ";
    cout <<"\n\t       2 : Five Dollar     :  " << line << "  :  ";
    cout <<"\n\t       3 : Ten Dollar      :  " << line << "  :  ";
    cout <<"\n\t       4 : Twenty Dollar   :  " << line << "  :  ";
    cout <<"\n\t       5 : Quarter         :  " << line << "  :  ";

    cout<<"\n\tTotal bill types found : " <<line <<endl;
}
```

I have tried a while loop that searches line by line, but it outputs 5 of the same menus with line updated for that text value. Here is the while loop.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile ("parking_account.txt");
    string line;

    getline(inputFile, line);
    while (inputFile)
    {
        cout <<"\n\t-------------------------------------------------------";
        cout <<"\n\t=======================================================";
        cout <<"\n\t              Parking Machine Accounts                 ";
        cout <<"\n\t=======================================================";
        cout <<"\n\tSr. No.  : Bill Name       :  Bill Count  :  Cost(in$) ";
        cout <<"\n\t-------------------------------------------------------";
        cout <<"\n\t       1 : One Dollar      :  " << line << "  :  ";
        cout <<"\n\t       2 : Five Dollar     :  " << line << "  :  ";
        cout <<"\n\t       3 : Ten Dollar      :  " << line << "  :  ";
        cout <<"\n\t       4 : Twenty Dollar   :  " << line << "  :  ";
        cout <<"\n\t       5 : Quarter         :  " << line << "  :  ";

        cout<<"\n\tTotal bill types found : " <<line <<endl;
        getline(inputFile, line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question and snippet refer to different input files, fix this

Comment: Also remove example output from cycle, it is for demonstration,  not for reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the extraction operator `>>`:

```
string dummy; //this holds those separators since I have assumed that the numbers are always in the same order
//alternately, you could extract this two `>>`'s at a time, processing the string that
//comes befor the number to determine where it should go. For simplicity, I have
//assumed that the order is always the same.

int total one, five, ten, twenty, quarter;
inputFile >> dummy >> total >> dummy >> one >> dummy >> five >> dummy >> ten >> dummy >> twenty >> dummy >> quarter;
```

What this does is first extract your "Total" string into `dummy`. Next, it extracts the value "5" into the integer `total`. After that, it extracts "One" into `dummy`, 400 into `one` as an integer, "Two" into `dummy`, "300" into `five` as an integer, and so forth. If I've mis-interpreted your string format it should be simple enough to modify the above to match.

You can then replace your `line` variable in your output with the appropriate variable holding the value you are interested in for your table (`one`, `five`, etc).

The `>>` operator is provided by `istream` and is useful for these sorts of scenarios. (it's useful to note that this works on `cin` as well since `cin`'s class is descended from `istream`, just as `ifstream` is descended from `istream`)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the file can be opened.
If you can open the file, read the values from the file into your variables.
You could do something like this:

If this is `parking_account.txt`:

```
5 400 300 200 50 500
```

And this is *main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream inputFile("parking_account.txt");
  string line = "";
  int total = 0;
  int one = 0;
  int five = 0;
  int ten = 0;
  int twenty = 0;
  int quarter = 0;

  if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Could not read from file" << endl;
  }
  else {
    inputFile >> total >> one >> five
    >> ten >> twenty >> quarter;
  }
  getline(inputFile, line);

  cout <<"\n\t-------------------------------------------------------";
  cout <<"\n\t=======================================================";
  cout <<"\n\t              Parking Machine Accounts                 ";
  cout <<"\n\t=======================================================";
  cout <<"\n\tSr. No.  : Bill Name       :  Bill Count  :  Cost(in$) ";
  cout <<"\n\t-------------------------------------------------------";
  cout <<"\n\t       1 : One Dollar      :  " << one << "  :  ";
  cout <<"\n\t       2 : Five Dollar     :  " << five << "  :  ";
  cout <<"\n\t       3 : Ten Dollar      :  " << ten << "  :  ";
  cout <<"\n\t       4 : Twenty Dollar   :  " << twenty << "  :  ";
  cout <<"\n\t       5 : Quarter         :  " << quarter << "  :  ";

  cout<<"\n\tTotal bill types found : " << total <<endl;

  return 0;
}
```